# /etc/chef-server directory not getting created at install

Tags: installation, chef-infra

I'm having trouble installing Chef Sever (12.0.3) on my Centos 6.4 virtual machine.  Whenever I install Chef Server and reconfigure with these commands, the **/etc/chef-server** does not get created:

```
rpm -ivh chef-server-core-12.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm    
chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

This is a problem because all of the **.pem** files for authentication do not get created as well.  Has anyone ran into this issue?  I've searched, but I haven't found anyone with this same issue so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also, I do have an FQDN set of the VM (I've made an entry in the /etc/hosts file).

Answer (score 2):

Jotun,
I think you may be needing the *.pem files and hence searching for chef-server directory.
Chef 12 does not create the **chef-server** directory and that is because there is no default user (admin incase of chef 11) in chef 12. So you have to exclusively create the user using the below command:

```
chef-server-ctl user-create any_user_name your_first_name your_last_name email password --filename FILE_NAME
```

this will create a user with admin rights and the **FILENAME** should be the path where the admin.pem will be created.

In the same way for org creation,

```
chef-server-ctl org-create org_short_name org_full_name --association_user admin --filename FILENAME
```

this will create a organization associated with the admin user and the **FILENAME** should be the path where the chef-validator.pem will be created.

You can proceed with the steps that you used in chef 11 and configure the workstation.

Comment: Thank you, ripevik.  I have not had a chance to test this, but you sound spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the reason this error was happening, but I just destroyed my VM and created a new one.  Sorry if you are looking at this in the future and still want to know what was causing this problem.